# Why is the $\infty$-norm of $H^\infty$ functions the same as the $\infty$-norm of the radial limits?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $H^\infty$ denote space of holomorphic and bounded functions on the unit disk $U$ in $\mathbb{C}.$ For $f \in H^\infty$ we let $||f||_\infty$ be the supremum of the values of $|f(z)|,$ where  $z \in U.$

One can show that any $f \in H^\infty$ has radial limits almost everywhere; denote the radial limit function by $f^*.$ On the unit circle, we have the $L^\infty$-norm. If we let $$||f^*||_\infty$$ be the $L^\infty$-norm on the unit circle, then why do we have that $$||f||_\infty = ||f^*||_\infty?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear  that $||f^*||_\infty\le||f||_\infty$, since the values of $f^*$ are limits of values of $f$ in the disk.

The other direction follows from the fact that $$f=P[f^*],$$where $P[.]$ denotes the Poisson integral.

(How do you prove *that*, you ask? For $0<r<1$ let $f_r(z)=f(rz)$. Then $f_r$ is continuous on the closed disk, so $f_r=P[f_r^*]$. Let $r\to1$ and apply dominated convergence.)

Comment: What function are you using to dominate $f_r(e^{i \theta})?$ I could only think of the non-tangential maximal functions, but that seems overkill.

Comment: @inequalitynoob2 Erm, we're given that $f$ is _bounded_. So we can use "$c$" to dominate $f_r$.